# Is it possible to revoke a tapkey grant via POST request?

Tags: tapkey

```
curl -X "POST" "https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/owners/xxx/grants/xxxx/revoke" \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx'
```

I get

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

I created a grant and I wanted to delete it because I was testing. I thought that revoke can be something similar. I guess I am wrong about the grant concept here.

1. Is there a way to delete grants?
2. Why the error message is telling me that the revoke endpoint does not support POST?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [documentation](https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_RevokeById) for this endpoint, you need to specify `dryRun` query parameter.

```
https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/owners/xxx/grants/xxxx/revoke?dryRun=false
```